# Google Apps Script triggers

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps

onInstall() triggers run when a script is installed from the add-on store or the script gallery. But we don't have Un-Install trigger to track uninstallation of the add-on.

Is there any way to trigger onUninstall in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported. OnInstall makes sense to prepare your app first time. Uninstall doesnt make much sense since your app won't run again.
If you want to provide some cleanup, provide it on a menu as a regular feature.